# Does vscode-remote auto commit my modification on files only exist in Images

Tags: vscode-remote

For normal Docker container, it does not save changes when container exit; But in vscode-remote, when i open my project in an container using settings devcontainer settings, the changes still exists every time i reopen vscode

My project is based on one image, i just want to open vscode remote to edit my project files, but when i changes the image files, my expectation is: changes being reverted when i reopen my vscode;

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "service": "xxx-service",
  "dockerComposeFile": "./docker-compose.yml",
  "workspaceFolder": "/home/rde",
  "postCreateCommand": "rde docker:run && yarn",
  "extensions": [],
  "settings": {
    "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
    "files.exclude": {}
  }
}
```